# Maven multiple parent-child hierarchy

Tags: maven

I have a project  that is built in the next manner:
parent module named **Production**, it holds two modules named **apps** and **libs**, each of them holds various projects.

```
Production
    apps
       common
       utils
    libs
       api
       dev
```

Production pom

```
<groupId>com.prod</groupId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>libs</module>
    <module>apps</module>
</modules>
```

Apps pom

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.prod</groupId>
    <artifactId>apps</artifactId>
</parent>


<modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>utild</module>
</modules>
```

Where packaging of **Production**, **apps** and **libs** is `pom`.
While the packaging for the rest is `war`/`jar`.

When I try to run `mvn install` on Production (or any other module/project) I get `Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find`

Only when I run `mvn install -N` on **Production**, **apps** and **libs**, I can finally start working with the projects.

Is there a better way to accomplish successful modules and projects alignment without running `mvn install -N`? some `pom` definition or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your POMs, I am guessing that you are missing `<module>` elements naming the children in Production, apps and libs POMs.

Once you have that, if everything else is in order, you can build from the Production folder with `mvn install` and have the reactor figure out what the right order to build the various modules are, subject to inter-module dependencies. Note that the `<module>` elements are relative paths to the child projects, not anything to do with the GAV of the project.

See http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html for more information about proper setup for multi-module projects.

Comment: I will add the pom in a few minutes

Comment: Good luck with Maven! If this helped you, please consider "accepting" the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll get to it only tomorrow, I'll let you know for the outcome.